# Is there a term for a "single mutex deadlock" (deadlock-type situation with non-recursive mutex)?

Tags: c++, mutex, deadlock

The following code hangs because of multiple calls to acquire a non-recursive mutex:

```
#include <pthread.h>

class Lock
{
public:

  Lock( pthread_mutex_t& mutex )
    : mutex_( mutex )
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_ );
  }

  ~Lock()
  {
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_ );
  }

private:

  pthread_mutex_t& mutex_;
};

class Foo
{
public:

  Foo()
  {
    pthread_mutex_init( &mutex_, NULL );
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &mutex_ );
  }

  void hang()
  {
    Lock l( mutex_ );
    subFunc();
  }

  void subFunc()
  {
    Lock l( mutex_ );
  }

private:

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.hang();
}
```

Is there a word or phrase for this situation? I'm not sure, but I don't think this can properly be called a deadlock: I'm of the understanding that a deadlock proper refers to the stalemate resulting from impassably ordered acquisition of *multiple* shared resources.

I've been anecdotally calling this a "single mutex deadlock" but I'd like to learn if there is a more proper term/phrase for this.

Comment: TIL that non-recursive is a synonym for non-reentrant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex

Comment: I believe that "deadlock" is still the most appropriate term, especially with the refinement of such.

Comment: It's not clear which of two very different things you're trying to find a term for. Are you trying to find a term for what this code is described to do by the relevant standards? Or are you trying to find a term for what actually happens when you run this code on your particular system where you observe the particular behavior you describe? Since this is UB per the standard, they are two very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article on reentrant mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) cites [*Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WVQF2PK2tlgC&pg=PA374) which uses the term "self-deadlock." This term seems pretty reasonable to me!

> ...mutexes come in two basic flavors: recursive and non-recursive. A recursive mutex allows re-entrant locking, in which a thread that has already locked a mutex can lock it again and progress. Non-recursive mutexes, in contrast, cannot: a second lock in the same thread results in **self-deadlock.** Non-recursive mutexes can potentially be much faster to lock and unlock than recursive mutexes, but the risk of self-deadlock means that care must be taken when an object calls any methods on itself, either directly or via a callback, because double-locking will cause the thread to hang.

(emphasis added)

Various search results across a variety of technologies corroborate the use of this term.

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/guide-35930/index.html
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2963138/fix-parallel-deadlock-or-self-deadlock-occurs-when-you-run-a-query-tha
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6692
- https://github.com/citusdata/citus/issues/1572

Answer (score 1):

"self deadlock" or "recursive deadlock".

Comment: Resources to such terms, or usages in papers/documentation, please! (I'm not saying this answer is 'wrong', but it could definitely use some supporting information - a simple link *and* excerpt/summary/justification can go a long way.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) this is *undefined behavior* to lock a default initialized `mutex` twice from the same thread:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, attempting to recursively lock the mutex results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I agree. I would call this "deadlock due to incorrect use of mutex".

Comment: Also according to the manual: _"If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, deadlock detection shall not be provided. Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock."_

Comment: @RaymondChen But there is no saying it wall always deadlock on all systems implementing `pthreads`. It is *undefined*.

Comment: @Galik Right, so it's "X due to incorrect use of mutex" where X is the behavior you observe (deadlock, memory corruption, exclusion violation, etc.) In this case X is "deadlock".